# Results are missing for Qiskit runtime program 'sample-expval'

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I have ran some circuits using the code for `sample-expval`, found in the [qiskit docs](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services?program=sample-expval)
While the jobs finished (they appear in my IBM account), when I retrieve some job and try to recover the result with `job.result()` what I obtain is just quotes: `''`

Here is the code that I ran:

```
job = provider.runtime.run(program_id='sample-expval',
                       options={'backend_name': 'ibmq_belem'},
                       inputs={'circuits':allcircuits_list[0],
                       'expectation_operators':all_zeros_proj,'shots':10000,
                       'use_measurement_mitigation':True})
```

`allcircuits_list[0]` is a list of circuits that I previously defined and `all_zeros_proj = {'00': 1}`

I also tried with the code indicated in the [qiskit tutorial](https://qiskit.org/documentation/partners/qiskit_runtime/tutorials/sample_expval_program/qiskit_runtime_expval_program.html)
which first defines a function `expectation_value_runner` that contains the input parameters. After introducing the inputs I ran

```
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_belem') 
job = expectation_value_runner(backend, allcircuits_list, all_zeros_proj)
```

In this case I have the same problem. No results are retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with Qiskit Runtime 2 days ago that result data was not being returned. The issue has since been fixed, so it should work now.